# Cell array text manipulation

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I need to keep only the elements after the nth place in a cell array.

*Example:*

```
cell_in = {'test string no (1)'; 
           'test string no (2)'; 
           'test string no (3)'}
```

and I need to get this result:

```
cell_out = {'no (1)'; 
            'no (2)'; 
            'no (3)'}
```

I have tried the following which failed:

```
cell_out = cell_in{:}(13:end)
```

Is there a way to sort this out, perhaps using `cellfun`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly apply an index to all cells' contents.

A way to achieve that you want is to use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply the desired indexing to all cells' contents via an [anonymous function](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
cell_out = cellfun(@(c) c(13:end), cell_in, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, thank you very much Luis!